# Converting a Lead into an existing opportunity

Tags: apex

I am looking at ways to convert a lead to an existing opportunity. I understand that we cant convert to an existing opportunity using apex as well (atleast i could not find an option in the documentation).

Are there any workarounds that can be used to convert into existing opportunity which somebody here has tried and worked.

Thanks

Comment: First, I've not attempted to do this and I don't know how you're doing your conversions as there are many ways to do them. It would seem to me that you'd simply want to convert the lead, then **add** them as a contact for the existing opportunity. Obviously, you can't recreate the opp, but with proper coding, I'd think you could add the new contact once you identified the opportunity.

Comment: This [blog](http://blog.deliveredinnovation.com/2014/02/05/salesforce-custom-convert-lead-page-and-lead-conversion-process-using-visualforce-and-apex/) is a good place to start.